# Setting the origin on a canvas

Tags: java, awt

I am trying to create a simple graphing program, and I want/need the origin to be at the bottom left corner, so I am using the following custom canvas:

```
public class GraphingCanvas extends Canvas {

    public GraphingCanvas() {

    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        ((Graphics2D) g).translate(this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
        g.translate(10, 10);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawLine(0, 0, 10, 10);
    }
}
```

However, when I use this canvas, like so:

```
private void initialize() {

    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    GraphingCanvas canvas = new GraphingCanvas();
    canvas.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    canvas.setBounds(10, 10, 414, 241);
    frame.getContentPane().add(canvas);
}
```

The origin appears to remain at the default. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I don't think you can...You "might" be able to scale the context by 0x-1, but I'm not sure that will achieve what you want (things will grow to the up, not down).  Instead, you should create a translation method which can convert your points from the normal top/left context to the bottom/left context that you want.

Comment: Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

Comment: Also, avoid mixing Swing and AWT components unnecessarily. Stick with all Swing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This may or may not do what you want, but basically I used `scale(1, -1)` to flip the orientation through the y-axis (and translated the context)

[image: FlipFlopped]

The magic basically happens in the `paintComponent` method using...

```
g2d.scale(1, -1);
g2d.translate(0, -getHeight());
```

Runnable example...

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private Rectangle box = new Rectangle(10, 10, 20, 20);

        public TestPane() {
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            draw(g2d, Color.RED, Color.MAGENTA);
            g2d.dispose();

            g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.scale(1, -1);
            g2d.translate(0, -getHeight());
            draw(g2d, Color.BLUE, Color.GREEN);
            g2d.dispose();
        }

        protected void draw(Graphics2D g2d, Color boxColor, Color lineColor) {

            g2d.setColor(boxColor);
            g2d.fill(box);
            g2d.setColor(lineColor);
            g2d.drawLine(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

        }

    }

}
```

Just to be sure, I created a simple method...

```
protected void draw(Graphics2D g2d, Color boxColor, Color lineColor) {
    g2d.setColor(boxColor);
    g2d.fill(box);
    g2d.setColor(lineColor);
    g2d.drawLine(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
}
```

which is called with the "normal" orientation and then called again with the transformed orientation, so it's the same code been used to paint the output, the only thing that's changed is the orientation

Comment: Love it! And you created and disposed a temporary Graphics2D object so as not to corrupt the JVM's Graphics object by affine transforming it.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I'm actually amazed it worked :P

Comment: Question: Would it not have the same

Comment: dang the enter button.... @MadProgrammer, question: wouldnt it be the same thing to just translate the origin to 0, height? considering setting the y scale negative and translating to negative height cancel eachother out, a scale of 1,1 and translating to 0, positive height would be the same, no?

Comment: No, translation moves the `0x0` point of the `Graphics` context to the new location, but Java's `Graphics` always draws right/down from `0x0`